# Troubleshooting python sys.path

Tags: python, path

The python docs at http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html say that `sys.path` is...

> Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default.

I found a path item in my `sys.path` that was causing problems, and had a lot of trouble tracking it down. All I could turn up on Google was people explaining how to *add* items to the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

My question is: are there any tools that can help track down *why* a particular item is on your `sys.path`? How can I find out more about the "installation-dependent default"?

So far, I've found a partial answer is to use `strace` on python itself and look for `.pth` files. I also found a `sys.path_importer_cache`, which may or may not be applicable.

Comment: The item in question was just my own package I had used "setup.py develop" on as root (shame on me). The OS is Ubuntu Linux, but python being a platform-independent language, I was looking less for a list of files/directories to check and more for documentation, general guidelines, or even links into the CPython source code.

Comment: BTW, I had already tracked down my specific issue and was mostly asking for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had some issues recently with `sys.path` and here is how I went about trying to figure out where the entries are coming from. I was able to track all the entries and where they were coming from. Hopefully this will help you too.

- The first that is added `C:\WINNT\system32\python27.zip` (more details in PEP273).
- Next ones that are added are from entries in windows registry. The entries `C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\lib; C:\Python27\lib\plat-win; C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk` come from `HOT_KEY_LOCAL_USER/Python/PythonCore/2.7/PythonPath` in the registry. More details in Python source code comments here http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/PC/getpathp.c (These entries were the trickiest for me to understand until I found the link above).
- Next, as explained in the `site` package documentation ([link](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html)), `sys.path` is built from `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`. On my computer both of them point to `C:\Python27`. And by default it searches the `lib/site-packages` anywways. So now the entries `C:\Python27; C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` are appended to the list above.
- Next it searches each of the `.pth` files in alphabetical order. I have `easy_install.pth`, `pywin32.pth` and `setuptools.pth` in my site-packages. This is where things start getting weird. It would be straightforward if the entries in the `.pth` files were just directory locations. They would just get appended to the `sys.path` line by line. However `easy_install.pth` has some python code that causes the entries listed in `easy_install.pth` to add the packages list at the *beginning* of the `sys.path` list.
- After this the directory entries in `pywin32.pth`, `setuptools.pth` are added at the end of the `sys.path` list as expected.

Note: While the above discussion pertains to Windows, it is similar even on Mac etc. On Mac it just adds different OS defaults like `darwin` etc. before it starts looking at `site-packages` directory for `.pth` files.

In your case, you can start by starting a python shell and checking where `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` point to and then drilling down from there.

Note 2: If you are using an IDE such as Aptana/PyDev it will add more configurations of its own. So you need to be wary of that.

Comment: kudos for the links. I couldn't find any analogue to `getpathp.c` for Mac or Linux. Is there one?

Comment: Thanks. Mac doesn't have a registry ... so it is not as straight forward as finding the right locations using registry keys. Also the locations for Mac will depend on the build options used when making the installer. FWIW, this is the best link about Mac. http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Mac/README. I checked on my Mac, and Python 2.7 did in fact install in the locations mentioned in that file.