# How exactly is Python2's sys.path set in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, path, pythonpath

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) says that `sys.path` is "Initialized from the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, plus an installation-dependent default."

But what is the "installation-dependent default" exactly for Windows?

(I know this is probably dependent on how python was compiled, but if all I have is the binary, is there any way to figure out how the default `sys.path` is constructed?)

**Clarification**:
I am not asking "What is my `sys.path`?".  I want to know "how does Python construct sys.path?"  Documentation says that `sys.path` is constructed with `sys.path[0]` being the script's current directory, plus whatever Python finds in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, plus some installation-dependent voodoo.  So what is this mysterious voodoo part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like [Praveen Gollakota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/553995/praveen-gollakota) has good info at [Troubleshooting python sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500736/troubleshooting-python-sys-path/5501462#5501462) (repasted here:)

- The first that is added C:\WINNT\system32\python27.zip (more details in [PEP273](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0273/)).
- Next ones that are added are from entries in windows registry. The entries `C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\lib; C:\Python27\lib\plat-win; C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk` come from `HOT_KEY_LOCAL_USER/Python/PythonCore/2.7/PythonPath` in the registry. More details in Python source code comments here http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/PC/getpathp.c (These entries were the trickiest for me to understand until I found the link above).
- Next, as explained in the [`site` package documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html), `sys.path` is built from `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`. On my computer both of them point to `C:\Python27`. And by default it searches the `lib/site-packages` anyway. So now the entries `C:\Python27; C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` are appended to the list above.
- Next it searches each of the `.pth` files in alphabetical order. I have `easy_install.pth`, `pywin32.pth` and `setuptools.pth` in my site-packages. This is where things start getting weird. It would be straightforward if the entries in the `.pth` files were just directory locations. They would just get appended to the `sys.path` line by line. However `easy_install.pth` has some python code that causes the entries listed in `easy_install.pth` to add the packages list at the beginning of the `sys.path` list.
- After this the directory entries in `pywin32.pth`, `setuptools.pth` are added at the end of the `sys.path` list as expected.

Note: While the above discussion pertains to Windows, it is similar even on Mac etc. On Mac it just adds different OS defaults like darwin etc. before it starts looking at `site-packages` directory for `.pth` files.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to examine the actual path in your python interpreter:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pprint, sys
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.0.0-py2.6.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python26.zip',
 'c:\\Python26\\DLLs',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'c:\\Python26',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'c:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing `sys` and then printing `sys.path`?  It would appear that it contains the following on my Windows 7 system:

```
'', 
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python26.zip', 
'c:\\python26\\DLLs', 
'c:\\python26\\lib', 
'c:\\python26\\lib\\plat-win', 
'c:\\python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 
'c:\\python26', 
'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages', 
'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 
'c:\\python26\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode'
```

This corresponds to the packages I've installed, as I haven't ever needed to set a custom PYTHONPATH variable.